# 12v Led Wiring Problem

Tags: wiring, switch

I have 2 strips of approximately 200 LEDs in each strip.  From the power source I run the negative to the negative on each strip and the positive to a switch.  From the switch I run to the positive on each strip.

My thinking was that this switch would turn the LED strips on and off.  However what I get is either one off and the other on or both on.

Where could have I gone wrong?

Comment: I think we are going to need a picture of the wiring added to this, its too vague otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you used a double throw switch and connected the lights to two different terminals on the switch. You need to connect the positive wires for the LED strip to the same terminal on the switch.

Comment: No just a normal two way switch and both are connected to the same terminal.

Comment: Post a picture of your work.